# Take CFN stack creation time for AWS EB scheduler, not project build time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript, aws-service-catalog

I have a problem working with AWS CDK JS Event Bridge Scheduler, I have a service catalog "ProductStack" and I defined the one-time scheduler in it, so ONLY when the user will provision that product - the scheduler will be created. Now, the problem is, I'm using js date for taking that provision time and adding 5 minutes to it, but it takes the build time of the whole CFN stack and not the provision time of the "ProductStack" defined in it. With this I end up with a situation, when the scheduler itself is created for ex. at 10:00, but it is set to be fired at 09:55. Here's the short definition  for my scheduler:

```js
this.scheduler = new CfnSchedule(this, `Something`, {
  flexibleTimeWindow: { mode: 'OFF' },
  scheduleExpression: `at(${ moment.utc().add(2, 'minutes').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') })`,
  scheduleExpressionTimezone: TimeZone.ETC_UTC.timezoneName,
  ...
});
```

instead of `moment.utc()` I used `date-fns` and js simple `new Date()` as well, but all of them end up with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to "do something after the stack is deployed", consider instead creating an EventBridge rule that listens to `CREATE_COMPLETE` stack events that CloudFormation [emits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacks-event-bridge.html#supported-events) to the default event bus.  The rule would trigger a target (e.g. Lambda) that runs when the stack is created.

However, if you really need to create a one-time scheduled event relative to the stack deploy time, you could shift the work of creating the schedule to a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources).  You'd write a Lambda with an SDK [CreateSchedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/scheduler/command/CreateScheduleCommand/) command, passing the current time from the Lambda runtime.  Hooked up as a Custom Function handler, the Lambda would be invoked at deploy time by CloudFormation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I know that option with custom resources, but initially my goal was to do everything w/ CDK only. Is there an option for it? Maybe tokenized date inside "ProductStack" or smth like that...

Comment: @DavidGabrielyan I don't think there is a synth-time token option.  There is no CloudFormation [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) or [pseudo parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) that produces a date.